# How to read data from USB OTG Pen Drive in android?

Tags: android, usb-drive, usb-otg, usb-mass-storage, android-usb

I am developing an application that have used of OTG Pen Drive, so concept like read data from OTG pen drive but all user have might not be a same device.

I have tested on 5-6 devices that were given me different different USB OTG path. And even on same device I have remove pen drive and inserted again it was shown me different folder name of path.so I am not able to find exact path for all users. So, my questions are :

1. How to get device is supported OTG or not programmatically ?
2. How to find exact path for USB Pen Drive OTG programmatically for all devices those supported OTG?
3. will it respond same path if user insert/remove multi times? and If user may be format Pen Drive then also ?

Comment: any idea on reading data from iPhone using OTG?. will iOS support this?

Answer (score 1):

I found one path to go in this direction is:

i found a project here : github.com/danny-source/List-USB-OTG

I have also asked the same question here:

[Play Video using connected USB via OTG cable in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29625384/play-video-using-connected-usb-via-otg-cable-in-andoid)

Comment: any idea on reading data from iPhone using OTG?. will iOS support this?