# Best way to determine the amount of space available for storing app files with Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uwp

From research I have found that it is possible to determine the available space for storing app files on **iOS**, **Android** and **UWP** using dependency services with the Platform specific code below:

**For iOS:**

```
private double GetRemainingStorageSpace(string directoryPath) 
{     
    var freeExternalStorage = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetFileSystemAttributes(directoryPath).FreeSize;
     return (double)freeExternalStorage;
 }
```

**For Android it can be done like:**

```
var path = new StatFs(directoryPath); long blockSize = path.BlockSizeLong; 
long avaliableBlocks = path.AvailableBlocksLong; 
double freeSpace = blockSize * avaliableBlocks;  
return freeSpace
```

or like this:

```
var fl = new Java.IO.File(directoryPath); 
var freeSpace = fl.UsableSpace;
return (double)freeSpace;
```

**For UWP:**

```
string freeSpaceKey = "System.FreeSpace";  
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(directoryPath); 
var properties = await folder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new string[] { freeSpaceKey });  
var freeSpace = properties[freeSpaceKey];  
return (UInt64)freeSpace;
```

My question then is:

1.) Do these lines of code above actually return the amount of bytes that can be stored in a specific directory? Or do they return the amount of bytes that can be stored on the whole device?

2.) For Android I am not too sure what the difference between the two ways of doing this are I am hoping for an explanation of the difference between the both of then and which is a better to use?

Would appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.) Do these lines of code above actually return the amount of bytes that can be stored in a specific directory? Or do they return the amount of bytes that can be stored on the whole device?

Obviously it is `specific directory` ,because in the code it needs  specific  folder path as parameter .

You can try to set **directoryPath** as
`System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`

and

`System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`

to see the difference.

---

> 2.) For Android I am not too sure what the difference between the two ways of doing this are I am hoping for an explanation of the difference between the both of then and which is a better to use?

I can't tell the difference or which is better, because based on my test the result comes the same , and for details you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663624/how-to-get-free-and-total-size-of-each-storagevolume) , it's maybe helpful .