# How to check if storage is calculated in base 10 or base 2 on Samsung devices?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

My Android app has a page that shows the phones free and total storage size. To get the storage information, I used the solution described in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663624/how-to-get-free-and-total-size-of-each-storagevolume).

This solution loops through all storage volumes, adds up the total space and returns the result in bytes.

I tested it on various devices and most of them returned an exact value that is divisible in base 10: For example, I got exactly 128000000000 bytes for an Asus 128GB device, and 32000000000 bytes for an older Pixel 32GB device.

But when I tested on a Samsung device, it returned 274877906944 bytes (256GB in base2).
Now my app UI is showing 275GB total storage for the Samsung 256GB device which confuses the user. Am I wrong to assume that the physical bytes available on any Android device will always be divisible by base 10?

When I check the storage info on other thrid-party File Manager apps including Google Files, they all seem to display the correct storage information no matter which  manufacturer.

So my question is: How do these apps know when to use base 10 or base 2 when calculating storage?

Comment: I wonder what you mean by base 2 and base 10.

Comment: 274877906944 / 1024 = 268 GB.

Answer (score 1):

A simple hack-  a base 2 number is never divisible by 10.  So if the size % 10 is not 0, then it's a base 2 size.

Comment: So you're saying that there is no number 2^n that exists which when modded by 10^n is equal to zero? Sorry for being bad at math.

Comment: 2^n numbers can never be divisible by 5 as the only prime factors they have are 2, and any number divisible by 10^n always ends in 0 due to how 10 and its powers work with multiplication

Comment: so 2^n numbers never end with zero right? Can I assume that if the total bytes does not end with 0, its definitely base 2?

Comment: O course not as with base 10 it can end on that too.